# How to use already created database?

Tags: vb6

How to select a same database?

I want to create a table from already created database.

Using vb6

My code.

```
Set db = DBEngine.CreateDatabase("1.mdb", dbLangGeneral)
```

I don't want to create database, I want to used already created database,  so 1.mdb is already created. I want to use the 1.mdb database

How to modify a code?

Need vb6 code Help

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: Compensate for lack of English by using greater number of words, it gives us a better chance of working out what you really mean.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb")
```